# error opening archive(7z) files in python when made by 7zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, 7zip, lzma

I have been learning python got the basics down

to get better I have been trying to create a program to open archive files, not create just open.

I can easily create and open 7z files however when the archive is created with 7zip it does not open it, anyone know why and how I can open files created by 7zip

```
  data = b"Insert Data Here"
  with lzma.open("file.7z", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)


  with lzma.LZMAFile("file.7z") as f:
        fc =f.read()
        print(fc)
```

the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Users\<name>\Documents\Py\decompression.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\<name>\Documents\Py\decompression.py", line 15, in main
    fc =f.read()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\lzma.py", line 291, in read
    return self._read_all()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\lzma.py", line 244, in _read_all
    while self._fill_buffer():
  File "C:\Python33\lib\lzma.py", line 238, in _fill_buffer
    self._buffer = self._decompressor.decompress(rawblock)
_lzma.LZMAError: Input format not supported by decoder
```

Comment: Do you use [`pylzma`](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma)?

Comment: no I use the built in lzma module

Comment: It work on my `Python 3.3.4` and `windows 8.1`. What's your OS and Python version?

Comment: did you create the 7z archive with 7zip as I mentioned when the archive is created by 7zip and not by the lzma module the above error occurs.                                                         I have not previously dealt with compressed files before so I do not know what the problem is same format(7z) ad same algorithm(LZMA2) so no idea why the lzma module can open it when it was used to archive exact same file

Comment: Looks like I have the same problem.  I can read the files with the command line utility 7z, but not via lzma library.  Python 3.5 on OSX.  I guess will have to revert to calling 7z directly.